# Why does Visual Studio Code send me: Language Support for Java (Syntax Server) client: couldn't create connection to server

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal, runtime-error, enoent

I am a student attempting to learn Java. I downloaded Visual studio code and it was working well until now. This is what shows when I try to run a program:

[Error - 10:04:09 PM] Language Support for Java (Syntax Server) client: couldn't create connection to server.
Launching server using command c:\Users\myname.vscode\extensions\redhat.java-1.18.0-win32-x64\jre\17.0.7-win32-x86_64\bin\java failed. Error: spawn c:\Users\myname.vscode\extensions\redhat.java-1.18.0-win32-x64\jre\17.0.7-win32-x86_64\bin\java ENOENT

It first gives me the message: "Language Support for Java (Syntax Server) client: couldn't create connection to server."

I don't understand what this means. I found a post saying that I had to install the latest version of Language support for java and I did that. I even deleted visual studio code and redownload and it is still the same. I followed the command line: c:\Users\myname.vscode\extensions\redhat.java-1.18.0-win32-x64\jre\17.0.7-win32-x86_64\bin\java up until bin but I didn't find a file with just java. The closes thing I found was java.exe is that the same thing?  I also found java.dll. I don't know what happened I just need for my code to run.

I found a post saying that I had to install the latest version of Language support for java and I did that. I even deleted visual studio code because I thought that if I  did something deleting the app then redownloading it would undo what I did. It did not work and it is still the same.

Comment: Does it works if you switch to pre-release version of [Language support for java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java)?